# Zoom images in MAUI C#

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to make the opportunity to zoom images in my MAUI app, but it doesn't works.

I've made a PinchZoomContainer like in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pinch?view=net-maui-7.0

My code:

```
 <viewmodelns:PinchToZoomContainer Grid.Row="0">
    <Image Source="images.png" />
</viewmodelns:PinchToZoomContainer>
```

PinchZoomContainer class have similar code as in example.

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3LV.png)

P.S. I'm from laptop, so I can use pinch gesture in my touchpad.

Comment: posting code as images is against the site rules.  Please [edit] your post and please read [ask] for an overview of the site guidelines

Comment: Tablet (touch screen) gestures are not necessarily the same thing as touchpad gestures. it may be that this container only recognizes tablet gestures.

Comment: @PaulDempsey I've checked that OnPinchUpdated event handler method invokes - it is being called.

Comment: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/blob/master/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls/Shared/Controls/ZoomImage.cs

Comment: It is recommended that you can use a physical device to test the project. Especially the  project use a pinch gesture.